# Logging a JSON object in firebase console

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know how to log JSON data in a readable manner to the firebase logs? When using:

`console.log(req.body)`

or

`` console.log(`${req.body.event}: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2)}`); ``

it prints it as seen in the picture below on multiple lines.

My firebase cloud functions run on Node 10

[image]

Comment: That's odd -- one `console.log` statement should result in one log to the online console.  Can you show your whole code, please?

Comment: Also, if the account id above is not just a dummy account, you may wish to consider redacting it for privacy.

Comment: Hi guys thanks, I edited the post, does that help?

Comment: Not familer with Firebase but if you want to have a friendly way to `console.log()` your data, maybe [console.table](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties)  helps in having data displayed in readable way.

Comment: I also have this issue, and it started after our update to node 10 in firebase functions. just logging a POJO now outputs one line per 'line' in the object

Comment: Also have this issue after updating to node 10, node 8 logs perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to use `functions.logger.log()` with Node version 10 and above. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm I have the same problem, since the update to Node 10 JSON objects are printed in multiple lines.

For now the solution is to import this dependency:

```
require('firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat');
```

Just put this at the top of your functions code.

You can check the official issue for updates: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/612

Answer (score 1):

This multi-line behavior is likely due to the fact that you explicitly tell JSON.stringify() to add line breaks and indentation. The last parameter (2) tells JSON formatter that you want "structured" (aka "pretty") output with 2 spaces per indentation level. If you drop the last argument (you may safely drop "null" as well), then you should see good old one long string :)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I don't see this logging behavior when using NodeJS 8 on my Firebase Functions. So something changed with Node 10 on the Firebase side...
Also check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/612

Comment: This does seem related to the node version. I'm seeing ths since updateing from v8 to v10.